# Merging GWT and Spring Security/Spring MVC

Tags: gwt, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a project that uses GWT for my front end, then the backend im using SpringMVC and im trying to merge in Spring Security and Spring Social.  I found the library GWTSecurity here:

https://code.google.com/p/gwtsecurity/wiki/DesignConsideration

and it seems to make my life much more pleasant in stitching these things together.  But I've run into a problem.  This document seems to be very clear, for a system that is a single project.  My particular project is split into two.  One MVC project that will be hosted on Jetty on one box, and a second GWT project that will be hosted on an apache on a second box.

Does anyone know this tool well enough to tell me if I have to install spring in my GWT project to get the thing to work, or do i put all the context listeners listed in this document into my MVC project and it all just magically wire up?

Comment: If you are using maven webapp project .You can easily create a war file and run in tomcat.And if u want to run gwt in jetty server.we can run maven gwt:run goal

Comment: I know both of these are possible.  The problem is first, i have no desire to use tomcat.  Jetty is our standard.  second, the UI of this app must be deployed to Apache servers, so using the server side of GWT is strictly out of the question.  Thats why im asking in which project the pieces of this gwtsecurity goes.  Because if i have to put spring into my GWT project to make it work, im monumentally screwed

Comment: Sorry if  i am wrong again we can use gwt with spring security in single project. Gwt code will function with module-gwt.xml. And in  web.xml we can configure our spring-security and related information of web app.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have `Spring` in your `GWT` app. I am using `Spring MVC` and `Spring Security` together with `GWT` in one of my projects and I actually have 3 distinct maven modules (using [Thomas Broyer's archetype](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes)):

- server (`Spring MVC`, `Spring Security`)
- shared (`RequestFactory` proxies, or shared classes)
- client (GWT,etc)

I am not using `GWTSecurity` but are doing it manually.
Actually `GWT` does not need to know anything about what kind of `Security` you have on the backend. I am using a dedicated login page.

What you probably have to do is to include the maven dependency to `GWTSecurity` to both your `GWT` (client) module and your `Spring` (server) module but you don't need to include the `Spring` module in your `GWT` module.

Comment: awesome, this is a step in the right direction.  My problem is im not familiar enough with the tools to put in the missing pieces.  Do you know of a tutorial or something that can pull the half a dozen or so moving parts together into a working copy?